# from string to command

Tags: strings

What exactly happens in:

```
\newcommand{\mystring}[1]{\gdef\@mystring{#1}}
```

when `\mystring{mystring}` is used later in the document? It is known that `mystring` will be put in `\mystring` but I would like to know how in a Latex sense.

**Edit:** More information is given below. My programming skills in general and especially my Latex programming skills are decently low. I want to prepare a template for conference proceedings where specific information should be stored in appropriate strings that can be used later. Typically, authors' names could be stored in *a variable* that we will call `\AuthorNames` so that `\AuthorNames` (or more exaclty `\@AuthorNames` as indicated by Ulrike) can be indicated in the right footer of the paper for instance. Since I do not know much, I decided to mimic existing Latex classes (probably the article class). By travelling through the class examples, I figured out that:

```
\newcommand{\AuthorNames}[1]{\gdef\@AuthorNames{#1}}
```

was doing was I needed. I can know reformulate my question through a comparison with FORTRAN. What is the LaTeX version of:

```
 CHARACTER :: AuthorNames
```

Or in other terms, is there a LaTeX guide somewhere saying: "if you want to declare a string of characters in LaTeX", use this: [blablabla]. I should probably read "texbytopic", that's all.

Comment: I really don't understand this question. Could you add a little more context?

Comment: `\gdef` is like `\newcommand` except it does not complain of the command is already defined and the definition is global so is not lost at the end of the next `{ }` group or environment. So basically  `\mystring{mystring}` does `\newcommand\@mystring{mystring}`

Comment: yes but the question behind is: why the command `\@mystring` contains the string `mystring`. Is this just the default functioning of such command? (in other words, is this the only way to assign a string of characters to a command in Latex)

Comment: "mystring" is not put in `\mystring` but in `\@mystring`. That's a different command. The purpose of `\mystring` is 1. to give a better interface. users can store a string with `\mystring{string}` instead of having to do `\gdef\@mystring....` and 2. in this way you can store the value in a command with @ in its name which can't be changed easily by a user and so it is (a bit) protected.

Comment: @pluton your question even after the comment above is not at all clear. But perhaps Ulrike's comment answered it. If not I suggest you edit your question to be more explicit, and we can try again.

Comment: @David: yes, Ulrike's comment helps but I edited my question to bring more insight on the "why of my question".

Comment: tex does not have strings its macros defined by def, newcommand etc store sequences of tokens, that may be characters, as in your example or may include other command tokens. as Ulrike said, you coul make users define the token directly but often it is nicer to use the format that you show where you give a more declaritive interface in which the macro holding the author name is hidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX is a macro replacement language. That means that when we do

```
\def\foo{bar}
```

TeX simply stores `bar` as the *replacement text* for `\foo`. Thus when we use `\foo`, TeX replaces it exactly with `bar`, and carries on working. The content of a macro is *not* a string: it's a token list: thus we can do

```
\def\fooa{\foob}
\def\foob{bar}
```

and see the same outcome (TeX replaces `\fooa` with `\foob`,then `\foob` with `bar`). LaTeX's `\newcommand` is a wrapper around `\def`, so the principal is identical (although `\newcommand` will complain if `\foo` already exists, which `\def` will not).

The `\gdef` primitive works in the same way as `\def` except it applies globally (`\def` is local, obeying TeX's grouping system). Thus

```
\newcommand{\AuthorNames}[1]{\gdef\@AuthorNames{#1}}
```

works by defining `\@AuthorNames` as a macro to be replaced by whatever is given as the argument to `\AuthorNames`. As mentioned in the comments, this approach means that the user has a simple interface

```
\AuthorNames{whatever}
```

rather than needing to know `\gdef` and why it should be used here.

TeX also has another form of token storage: the token register or 'toks'. There are reasons for picking a toks over a macro for storage in some cases. However, most of the time you can happily use a macro: they are in many ways more convenient.

Comment: Maybe to make things clear, just a remark that `@` is treated as a letter in some contexts, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/11002